# Retrofit работа с несколькими GET запросами

Tags: android, retrofit

У меня есть RecyclerView, в который я хочу поместить имя пользователя и его репрозитории.

Как мне запросить одновременно два GET запроса?

Интерфейс:

```
public interface GitHubApi {

    @GET("/users/{user}/repos")
    Call<List<GitHubRepos>> userRepos(@Path("user") String user);

    @GET("/users/{user}")
    Call<List<GitHubRepos>> userName(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

Класс(Здесь я выполняю запрос одного метода,а мне нужно получить два):

```
Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        final GitHubApi gitHubApi=retrofit.create(GitHubApi.class);

        final Call<List<GitHubRepos>> repos=gitHubApi.userRepos("shcherbuk96");

        repos.enqueue(new Callback<List<GitHubRepos>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<GitHubRepos>> call, Response<List<GitHubRepos>> response) {
                gitHubRepos=response.body();
                adapter=new RecyclerAdapter(gitHubRepos);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<GitHubRepos>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете асинхронный механизм получение данных.
У объекта Call<> есть метод execute(), который выполняет синхронный запрос.

```
Response<List<GitHubRepos>> repos1 = gitHubApi.userRepos("shcherbuk96").execute();
Response<List<GitHubRepos>> repos2 = gitHubApi.userName("shcherbuk96").execute();
```

После с объекта Response вы можете получить свои данные, через метод body().

Пример:
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-error-handling-for-synchronous-requests

Comment: Да, но этот код необходимо поместить в отдельный поток, иначе будет `NetworkOnMainThreadException`